# DLL Load Failed While Importing arcgisscripting: %1 is not a valid Win32 Application

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pycharm

I am experiencing an issue with loading the arcgisscripting module in Python. I am consistently receiving the error: "DLL load failed while importing arcgisscripting: %1 is not a valid Win32 application". This error occurs when I am running my Python scripts in PyCharm and when I am trying to import arcgisscripting in a Python shell.

I am currently using ArcGIS Pro 3.3.3, and I am trying to run my scripts in a conda environment cloned from the default ArcGIS Pro Python environment. The path to my Python executable in the cloned environment is:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\python.exe
```

I have checked the bitness of both the Python executable and the arcgisscripting module using the 'platform' module and the 'pefile' module respectively, and they both appear to be 64-bit. I have also ensured that the arcgisscripting module exists in the correct directory.

Here are the details of my system:

Operating System: Windows 10
Operating System Version: 10.0.19045
System Type: AMD64
Python Version: 3.9.16
Python Executable: C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone\python.exe
Processor Info: Intel64 Family 6 Model 154 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
PATH variable includes: C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin

I have tried solutions recommended on ESRI and Stack Exchange forums, such as reinstalling ArcGIS Pro and PyCharm, but to no avail. I should note that I am on a work laptop and do have administrative privileges, but they are only local.

Comment: It seems that there is a solution [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/dll-load-failed-while-importing-arcgisscripting/td-p/1266415)